# Using Liquibase with Azure SQL And Azure Active Directory Authentication

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, liquibase

How can you use Liquibase with an Azure SQL database and Azure Active Directory Authentication? Specifically, I want to connect using ActiveDirectoryPassword authentication mode as documented here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-using-azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15#connecting-using-activedirectorypassword-authentication-mode

I cannot figure out how to call the Liquibase CLI to make this happen.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get this to work. I am not very familiar with Java (we use Liquibase with a C# project), so I think some of the Java pieces tripped me up.

There were a few things I had to do to make this work:

1. I needed to add some properties to the URL I sent to Liquibase:

`--url="jdbc:sqlserver://REDACTED.database.windows.net;databaseName=REDACTED;authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true"`

**ActiveDirectoryPassword** is what tells the driver to use the authentication mechanism I wanted. I also had to add encrypt=true and trustServerCertificate=true to avoid some SSL errors I was getting (from:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-with-ssl-encryption?view=sql-server-ver15).

2. I needed the MSAL4J (Azure Active Directory) libraries in my classpath. I added them to the liquibase/lib directory so that the default Liquibase launcher scripts would add them for me. I got caught on this, too, because I needed to use Maven which we do not use. After downloading Maven, I used the copy-dependencies plugin to download the dependencies I needed.

   > mvn dependency:copy-dependencies

Here was the simple pom.xml I used:

```xml
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>adal4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I also put these dependencies in the liquibase/lib directory so they were automatically included in the classpath. The instructions from Microsoft were helpful in leading me to the correct places:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-using-azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15#connecting-using-activedirectorypassword-authentication-mode

Also, not sure it was required to meet my goal, but I upgraded to the latest Liquibase (3.8.7) and latest SQL Server drivers (8.2):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15